# How to replace a specific text by another in Response in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, globalization

fro globalization for arabian contries I want to show digits to arabic ones.such as 1--> ۱ ,2--> ۲ ,3-->۳ ....

Is there any way to replace a specific text by another at response?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string ToArabic(string input, string cultureName)
{
    CultureInfo culture= new CultureInfo(cultureName);
    var arabicDigits = culture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits;
    for (int i = 0; i < arabicDigits.Length; i++)
    {
       input = input.Replace(i.ToString(), arabicDigits[i]);
    }
    return input;
}
```

take client culture`(e.g. "fa-IR")` and pass it to above method

Comment: Thanks but you do this for strings but I want it for respose.can we generalize it for Response?